# Excessive resource usage / virtual memory size

Tags: server

Our server is generating lots of emails that follow this template:

**subject**:

```
lfd on host.foo.com: Excessive resource usage: foo (24056 (Parent PID:16356))
```

**body**:

```
Time:         Wed Jan 31 11:31:20 2018 -0500
Account:      foo
Resource:     Virtual Memory Size
Exceeded:     556 > 512 (MB)
Executable:   /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
Command Line: /opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/foo/public_html/index.php
PID:          24056 (Parent PID:16356)
Killed:       No
```

Sometimes I can attribute these to image transforms, but other times they appear somewhat randomly. I received 13 in a row earlier today. I've seen this type of email from several servers that run Craft sites. I've researched excessive resource emails in general, but the answer always seems to be "just add it to csf.pignore" - which I don't want to do.

So, I'm wondering if anyone knows what Craft process may be generating this type of email. I don't think that we're doing anything out of the ordinary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears those emails are being generated by something called [Config Server Firewall](https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/disable-lfd-excessive-resource-usage-alert/) running on your server.  I don't know if your host gives you access to configure settings in it, but it looks like they have allocated you 512M of memory and you're exceeding that.

You can hit that easy enough with image transforms and spikes/surges in traffic can amplify that effect.

Comment: Thanks @brad-bell. Yes, these emails are coming from CSF. I've increased PT_USERMEM to 1024MB so that should help quite a bit. I still don't know the difference btw virtual memory and swap, but it's encouraging to know that I can safely set a high threshold. And it's especially helpful to know that a traffic spike could be causing virtual memory to be used. Cheers!

Comment: Oh and here's [Digital Ocean's explanation of Virtual Memory](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-virtual-memory-swap-file-on-a-vps).